# Rails update_Attributes(params[:user])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User show function that makes an api call and updates the user attributes, but I'm having trouble saving the changes.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ... change attributes of @user ...
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    p "Saved"
  else
    p "Failed"
  end
end
```

I'm updated two attributes (:today_steps and :year). Both are accessible in the user.rb. The challenge is that :year is a Serialized Array, but I'm not sure how that changes anything

this setup has returned a 'Failed' every time. i have also tried 'params[:id]' but I receive the error

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "1":String
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? thanks

***more info***

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if (@user.device != nil)
  @device = @user.device

  client = Fitgem::Client.new(
  #api client - haven't figured out my security yet, so I won't post it
  )
  now =  Time.now()
  last = @device.lastUpdated
  while now.to_date > last.to_date
    day = client.activities_on_date last.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    break if day['errors'] != nil
    day = day['summary']['steps']
    last = last + 1.days
    @user.year = @user.year.unshift(day)
  end
  day = (client.activities_on_date 'today')
  if day['errors'] == nil
    @user.today_steps = day['summary']['steps']
    if now.day != last.day
      @user.year.unshift(@user.today_steps)
    else
      @user.year[0] = @user.today_steps
    end
  end

  @device.lastUpdated = now
  p @user.year

  @user.device.save
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    p "Updated"
  else 
    p "Failed to Update"
  end
end
@competitions = @user.competitions.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

_

```
User.rb
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :year, :today_steps
  serialize :year, Array
```

**Even More**

console, using params[:user]

```
Started GET "/users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-25 17:15:09 -0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Device Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "devices" SET "lastUpdated" = '2014-02-26 01:15:09.634622', "updated_at" = '2014-02-26 01:15:10.392810' WHERE "devices"."id" = 3
   (2.3ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") =     LOWER('fire@fox.com') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '1f47eae1cb002cb1c4e83ce0363fbfb2d33ad8f5' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

console @user after find

```
#<User id: 1, name: "Marcus", email: "mar@comcast.net", points: nil, created_at: "2014-02-25 21:59:12", updated_at: "2014-02-25 21:59:12", password_digest: "$2aGTx..FbLP...", admin: false, remember_token: "e4bdd9c", year: [], lastUpdate: nil, lastUpdated: nil, today_steps: nil>
```

Comment: `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` might override your changes, as it applies any value from the `params[:user]` hash. Could you please post the whole body of the method, the content of `params`, the error you are getting (`@user.errors.full_messages`) and the data types of the model?

Comment: If you're updating the attributes of the user in the `... change attributes of @user ...` code. Can you just save the user? `if @user.save ...`?

Comment: No, @user.save doesn't work for some reason, not sure why

Comment: Could you clarify: are you saying User.find(params[:id]) fails with the stringify_keys error?  Or are you saying if you input @user.update_attributes(params[:id]), that fails with the stringify_keys error?

Comment: @user.update_attributes(params[:id]) returns the errors. Right before I save, I print out @user.year and it prints correctly, but isn't saved, so the next time the page is loaded, that data is lost

Comment: @Mhsmith21 Share the server log for your show action.

Comment: can you paste your params please

Comment: Updated the question with the info

Answer (score 0):

Your code is as

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
 ... change attributes of @user ...
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

#the log
Started GET "/users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-25 17:15:09 -0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
```

the log clearly states that the show method receives only 'id' whereas in your controller your expect a hash 'user' which can be supplied to update_attributes.

'show' expects to get an attributes hash to stringify it's keys for the column names.

Comment: When I use params[:id] I get the error: 'undefined method `stringify_keys' for "1":String' any ideas? (no method error)

Comment: can u paste the User model? Please print the object after 'find'.